# Loading chlid data using Eager loading in Entity Framework Include()

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I want to load child data from tables in entity framework using eager loading, but I am not getting the desired result. I want `tb_Event` data and then the customer data referenced by this table and then the data from `EventLocation` table and finally the data from `tb_Facility` and `tb_Location` based on `tb_EventLocation`.

This is what I did- till `eventlocation` I am gettting correct data but in `tb_location` and `tb_Facility` I am getting Cyclic dependency. Please help.

```
public IQueryable<tb_Event> Gettb_Event(){

    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    return db.tb_Event
        .Include(tb_Event=> tb_Event.tb_Customer)
        .Include("tb_Event=>tb_Event.tb_EventLocation")
        .Include("tb_EventLocation.tb_Location")
        .Include("tb_EventLocation.tb_Facility");
}
```

Comment: You need use `.Include(tb_Event=> tb_Event.tb_Customer)
            .ThenInclude("tb_Event=>tb_Event.tb_EventLocation")....`

Comment: public IQueryable<tb_Event> Gettb_Event()
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return db.tb_Event
                .Include(e => e.tb_Customer)
                .Include(e => e.tb_EventLocation.Select(el =>el.tb_Location))
                .Include(e => e.tb_EventLocation.Select(el => el.tb_Facility));
                

           
        }
Will this work?? @M.Wiśnicki

Comment: `.ThenInclude()` will chain off of either the last `.ThenInclude()` or the last `.Include()`.

Comment: .ThenInclude() is not showing up for me. @M.Wiśnicki

Comment: I think `.ThenInclude()` is available only in EF Core. Instead of last two includes, try using `.Include(tb_Event=>tb_Event.tb_EventLocation.tb_Location); and .Include(tb_Event=>tb_Event.tb_EventLocation.tb_Facility);`

Comment: Then how to solve my problem? @Developer

Comment: @Prabhjot - I have updated my last comment. That comment is with the assumption that `tb_EventLocation` is an object and not a collection. if its a collection then `.Include(tb_Event=>tb_Event.tb_EventLocation.Select(el=>el.tb_Location))`

Comment: @Developer- This is not working. See my first comment I have already tried implementing this.

Comment: I hope the quotes `"` in the line `.Include("tb_Event=>tb_Event.tb_EventLocation")` is a typo while posting it in SO. If not, do remove those quotes.